# Repeating a block of code until the block itself returns false?

Tags: ruby, loops

I want to:

1. pass a block to a method call, and then
2. pass that entire method call as the condition of a `while` loop,
3. even though I don't need to put any logic inside the loop itself.

Specifically, I have an array that I'd like to `#reject!` certain elements from based on rather complicated logic. Subsequent calls to `#reject!` may remove elements that were not removed on a previous pass. When `#reject!` finally stops finding elements to reject, it will return `nil`. At this point, I would like the loop to stop and the program to proceed.

I thought I could do the following:

```rb
while array.reject! do |element|
    ...
  end
end
```

I haven't actually tried it yet, but this construction throws vim's ruby syntax highlighter for a loop (*i.e.,* it thinks the first `do` is for the `while` statement, and thinks the second `end` is actually the end of the encapsulating method). I also tried rewriting this as an inline `while` modifier attached to a `begin...end` block,

```rb
begin; end while array.reject! do |element|
  ...
end
```

but it still screws up the highlighting in the same way. In any case, it feels like an abuse of the `while` loop.

The only way I could think of to accomplish this is by assigning the method call as a proc:

```rb
proc = Proc.new do
         array.reject! do |element|
           ...
         end
       end

while proc.call do; end
```

which works but feels kludgy, especially with the trailing `do; end`.

Is there any elegant way to accomplish this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My personal preference in situations where I need to call a method until the return value is what I want is:

```
:keep_going while my_method
```

Or more tersely I sometimes use:

```
:go while my_method
```

It's one line, and you can use the contents of the symbol to help document what's going on. With your block, I'd personally create a proc/lambda out of it and pass that to reject for clarity.

```
# Harder to follow, IMHO
:keep_going while array.reject! do |...|
  more_code
end

# Easier to follow, IMHO
simplify = ->(...){ ... }
:keep_simplifying while array.reject!(&simplify)
```

Comment: Oh yeah. You _are_ on SO. -_-' I liked your answer on reddit (incidentally, same as Stefan's above), but this wins it for readability.

Answer (score 5):

It's not just vim, `while array.reject! do |element|` is invalid syntax:

```
$ ruby -c -e 'while array.reject! do |element| end'
-e:1: syntax error, unexpected '|'
while array.reject! do |element| end
                        ^
```

You could use `{ ... }` instead of `do ... end`:

```
while array.reject! { |element|
    # ...
  }
end
```

or `loop` and `break`:

```
loop do
  break unless array.reject! do |element|
    # ...
  end
end
```

a little more explicit:

```
loop do
  r = array.reject! do |element|
    # ...
  end
  break unless r
end
```

Comment: Using `loop do` would be clearer than using a `while` block.

Comment: @theTinMan : I find the `while` block perfectly readable, but it's probably a matter of taste. Are there objective arguments for `loop do`?

Comment: There are readability issues mentioned in several style guides when using `while`, and a `loop` construct was recommended. While Ruby isn't Perl, the Perl language has several good writeups why to use certain constructs over others; Unfortunately Ruby's documentation and styles are not nearly as well defined. Some of the things in the Perl style guides I disagree with but in a team environment I bow to the clearest, most easily read code because we never know who's going to be debugging production problems late at night.

Answer (score 5):

Ruby lets you move your condition to the end of the loop statement. This makes it easy to store a result inside of the loop and check it against the conditional:

```
begin
  any_rejected = arr.reject! { … }
end while any_rejected
```

This would work the same as doing `end while arr.reject! { … }`, but it's much clearer here what's happening, especially with a complicated `reject!`.

Comment: This is much cleaner than nesting the `reject!` within the conditional or using a proc, and would prompt fewer wtf moments.

Comment: IIRC, Matz discourages the use of `begin ... end while condition`

Comment: @Stefan AFAIK, it was David Flanagan that discouraged it, and only because it's often counterintuitive, like when someone sticks a condition like `x == 0` at the end. A named variable condition resolves much of this confusion.

Answer (score 2):

You're right that the Ruby parser thinks that `do` belongs to `while`, and doesn't understand where the second `end` is coming from. It's a precedence problem.

This code is just to show that it **can** be done. For how it **should** be done, see Stefan's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41746233/6419007) :

```
array = (1..1000).to_a

while (array.reject! do |element|
    rand < 0.5
  end)
  p array.size
end
```

It outputs :

```
473
238
113
47
30
18
8
1
0
```

Comment: Those parenthesis really reduce readability/maintainability. As is said, while the code could be written that way, it shouldn't be. I'd call out the programmer in a code review and request it be done using `loop do`.

Comment: Sure. This should never be written that way. Still, the OP was surprised that it didn't work, so I just wrote a possible, yet ugly, fix.